# Microsoft VBScript Runtime error: Permission denied code 800A0046

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, user-permissions, vbscript

I am testing a VBScript and it was working fine earlier. Wanted to try with a different file input, but all of a sudden I'm getting `Microsoft VBScript Runtime error: Permission denied code 800A0046`. The script was working just fine a few hours ago? No one else is working on this server nor file..

I noticed that the folder will not remove "read-only", but I assigned myself read and write access under the security tab.. What's going on here? Why will this file all of a sudden not give me permission?

It's Windows Server 2012, I have admin rights.

Comment: Folders will always show the "Read only" box checked.